# Is there any way to get XAML element by Tag property?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

```
Is there any way to get the XAML element by its tag value??
```

My code is like this :

```
<Grid Tap="StackPanel_Tap" Tag="{Binding Type}" >
       <Border BorderThickness="0"  CornerRadius="0"  BorderBrush="White" Width="100" Height="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" >
      <Image Tag="{Binding Type}" Source="{Binding Location}" Opacity="1" Width="100"  Height="100" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True"  >
       </Image>
      </Border>
</Grid>
```

I am binding Tag Property for Grid , is there any way to get an object of Grid by using Tag Propertty??

Sorry for less information the thing is grid is in ListBox ..
How can i Access The Grid Object??

Thanks and Reagrds
Yashavantha

Answer (score 2):

Create a recursive method which uses System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper to get all children of the page. For each child test if it's of type Grid and if it has a Tag equal to whatever you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you.. I will check and let you know

Comment: The answer you told works fine if the Grid is outside...What if the Grid is in ListBox???