# How to get an element in ListBox by its tag name?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to get XAML element by Tag property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408473/is-there-any-way-to-get-xaml-element-by-tag-property)

I have a code like this:

```
                <ListBox x:Name="ImageListBox"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     Height="100"  >

                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel  ItemHeight="100" ItemWidth="110" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Tap="StackPanel_Tap" Tag="{Binding Type}" Name="Yashu">
                            <Border BorderThickness="{Binding Thickness}"  CornerRadius="0"   BorderBrush="White" Width="100" Height="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="1" >
                                <!--<Grid>-->
                                <Image Tag="{Binding Type}" Source="{Binding Location}" Opacity="1" Width="100"  Height="100" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" UseLayoutRounding="True"  >
                                </Image>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

How to get an grid element in ListBox by its tag name?

Answer (score 0):

In the event handler `StackPanel_Tap`, convert the sender to grid.

`object tag = (sender as Grid).Tag;`

and to get the grid element use `Grid grid1 = sender as Grid;`

Note: This works only if user taps on an item. I hope it helps

Comment: thank you i had done that..i want to pre select the item in listbox